# Can't console log the data from a data stream coming from an API, using ionic

Tags: ionic-framework

I have a running stream of data from a live scoring API but I cant seem to console log the data.

I am using an httpclient get method in ionic to get the request with observable as its return type.

How do I extract the data from that return or is there no return at all?

[image]

API Get:

```
getTest(apiUrl):
 Observable<any[]>{
 return this.httpClient.get<any[]>(apiUrl);
 }
 Provider:
 public getTestData(){
 return this.api.getTest(this.matchUrl).map(
 data => {
 return data;
 });
 } in page ts:
 getTest(){
 this.liveProvider.getTestData().subscribe(result => {
 var test0 = result;
 console.log(test0);
 });
 }
```

Comment: can u post api code and how your trying to console it

Comment: Api Get: 
   getTest(apiUrl): Observable<any[]>{
    return this.httpClient.get<any[]>(apiUrl);
  }
Provider:
public getTestData(){
    return this.api.getTest(this.matchUrl).map( data => {
      return data;
    });
  }
in page ts:
getTest(){
    this.liveProvider.getTestData().subscribe(result => {
      var test0 = result;
      console.log(test0);
    });
  }

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=166LLPe5Bw4MuiL8HC0JYKRzR8N0rNepq here is the link of the screenshot of how I did the code